# Rust: "the type of this value must be known in this context" error for Float::pi

Tags: rust, type-inference

I have the following line of code which I expect to just work:

```
const pi_n4th_root : f32 = Float::pi().powf(-1.0/4.0);
```

but it produces the following error:

```
f.rs:7:28: 7:54 error: the type of this value must be known in this context
f.rs:7 const pi_n4th_root : f32 = Float::pi().powf(-1.0/4.0);
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I tried to add every type annotation that I can:

```
const pi_n4th_root : f32 = (Float::pi() as f32).powf(-1.0/4.0 as f32) as f32;
```

but it still fails with the same error:

```
f.rs:7:30: 9:55 error: the type of this value must be known in this context
f.rs:7 const pi_m4th_root : f32 = (Float::pi::<f32>() as f32).powf(-1.0/4.0 as f32) as f32;
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Seems that I need to specify somehow that `Float::pi` is called for the f32 type but how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you want to do won't work for two reasons.

First, you can't write anything like this:

```
const pi_n4th_root : f32 = Float::pi().powf(-1.0/4.0);
```

That is, you can't call any functions in constant definitions, because exact values of constants should be known to the compiler, and Rust does not have compile-time function evaluation yet.

Second, as UFCS is [not yet implemented](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/16293), you cannot invoke trait methods for some specific type directly. I'm not sure why `Float::pi() as f32` does not work, but you can't specify desired type in paths too. The only way to do it would be writing a separate function:

```
#[inline]
pub fn pi<T: Float>() -> T { Float::pi() }
```

There are many such functions in Rust standard library. For Pi constant, however, there is a better way - you can use the constant of appropriate type directly:

```
use std::f32;

let pi = f32::consts::PI;
```

You can find a list of constants [here](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/f32/consts/) and [here](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/f64/consts/) (you can press [src] link if the page itself is empty, seems to be a bug in Rustdoc).

Comment: The constants are visible on the doc page of `core::f64::consts` however ( http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/f64/consts/ ).

Comment: @Levans, I thought it was probably a bug in Rustdoc JS or something like that because when I press \[src\] link these constants become visible for a moment, just before sources page is opened. Thanks for links, anyway.

Comment: Yeah, the docs first redirect you to `core::f64::consts` before printing the sources.

Comment: Wow, didn't notice that. Good to know)

Comment: It doesn't work even in non compile-time. I still get this "error: the type of this value must be known in this context". How to call Float::pi()?

Comment: You can do it like this: `let p: f64 = Float::pi()`, or somewhere else where type is statically known in advance, e.g. in a monomorphic function argument. Otherwise it is impossible until UFCS is implemented.